# How to run an ASP.NET Application on Another System?

Tags: visual-studio, web-applications

I have developed an ASP.NET web application in visual studio 2008. I want to run the same application on another system, but Visual Studio is not installed on that system. Is there a way I can run  without visual studio?

I heard about deploying, but I don't know much about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can publish your site from Visual Studio to a server that's running IIS, more info here:

[How to: Publish Web Application Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983453.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in deployment features of Visual Studio (right click on the web project, select publish and follow the prompts) or you can simply copy all the dlls plus your content files from the web project to the IIS folder you want to deploy to (known as xcopy deployment). You could also deploy via a setup project, which will create an MSI package, but that's a bit more work. Here's a couple of links that might help, but you can do a search for the options described above and you will find plenty of resources:

[Deploying ASP.NET Applications - Part 1](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/030806.htm)

[Deploying ASP.NET Applications - Part 2](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/030820.htm)